# Chicken or Egg... Define Engine before Export to MySQL from Access, how?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In a bit of a quandary here, having been trying many ideas I think I'm stuck with a several hour export.

I have a handful of queries that export out to MySQL from Microsoft Access every 24 hours, problem is one of the exports takes around an hour and a half to complete.

MySQL database defaults to InnoDB engine but isn't MyISAM faster for adding data? If I use the ODBC or DoCmd.TransferDatabase I can only edit the database to be MyISAM after the slow export has taken place, is there a faster way to export the data?

The data set being exported that takes so long is circa 40,000 records (10 columns of data). Should it really take this long?

My current workflow in the VBA has been to connect to MySQL and drop the table before recreating it. Like I say this works okay until it comes to the huge table - may have another this size soon and really don't want several hours to get the data across. Any help welcome please.

Have tried the following connection which matches the ODBC I have setup (and have tried the Macro calling saved export procedure):

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
        Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
        ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

SQLStr = "CREATE TABLE " & tblName & "(Code VARCHAR(10), Name VARCHAR(255), RegionCode VARCHAR(11), RegionName VARCHAR(100), CountryCode VARCHAR(10), CountryName VARCHAR(255), Address1 VARCHAR(255), Address2 VARCHAR(255), Address3 VARCHAR(255), Address4 VARCHAR(255), PostCode VARCHAR(20), Phone VARCHAR(30));"

rs.Open SQLStr, cn, adOpenStatic

SQLStr = "INSERT INTO " & tblName & " SELECT * FROM qryQuery1;"
```

Comment: I wonder would file DSN or a connection string help? `INSERT INTO [ODBC;DSN=DSNName;].NameOfMySQLTable SELECT AnyField As NameOfMySQLField FROM NameOfAccessTable`

Comment: would it be much easier, if you export the result into excel, prepare/modify the result as SQL satement again save as .sql/text file and import into MySQL?